# Mapping annotations in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, struts2

When I'm trying to add a new record in Work_orders table I get an error:

```
Dec 09, 2014 8:44:17 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'saveWorkOrder' in 
namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
```

I have a simple dao class to save and select records. I use 3 tables and 2 foreign keys.

WorkOrders.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Work_orders", schema="handyman")
public class WorkOrder implements Serializable {

....

@ManyToOne  
// @JoinColumn(name = "Companys_list_id") 
//@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="Companys_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Company company;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="Handymans_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Handyman handyman;
....
getters and setters
```

WorkOrderDaoHibernate.java

```
public class WorkOrderDaoHibernate implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public WorkOrder saveWorkOrder(WorkOrder workOrder)
{
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session =  sf.openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    Integer id = (Integer) session.save(workOrder);
    trans.commit();
    workOrder.setId(id);
    session.close();
    return workOrder;
```

Hibernate configuration file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/handyman</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">1982</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <!--  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> -->

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <!-- <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>  -->

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->

    <mapping class="com.handyman.model.Company" />
    <mapping class="com.handyman.model.Handyman" />
    <mapping class="com.handyman.model.WorkOrder" />




</session-factory>
```

Comment: can you post your hibernate configuration file.

Comment: @user2900314 just posted

Comment: hibernate configuration file is an xml file default file name would be  hibernate.cfg.xml. Its here where you specify required Hibernate properties and mapping resources. Incase if you are working for a corporate then remove the password and username and then  post it.

Comment: There's no Hibernate exception. Only some xwork2 warning.

Answer (score 0):

In your HibernateUtil Class, inside buildSessionFactory() method  try making this change and let me know what happens

```
configuration= configuration.configure();
```

Comment: I don't think it will change anything, mine is the same:   private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

     Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
     configuration.configure();